# Dart await removes then?

Tags: dart

Do await remove "then"?

Why is it that when using then in the following is causing this error:

```
// Error: [dart] The method 'then' isn't defined for the class 'String'. [undefined_method]
```

Modified code from [here](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/477fb799d21401f46f8c04462fd249c4)

```
import 'dart:async';

Future<void> printDailyNewsDigest() async {
  var newsDigest = await gatherNewsReports();
  // Error: [dart] The method 'then' isn't defined for the class 'String'. [undefined_method]
  newsDigest.then(print);
  // print(newsDigest);
}

main() {
  printDailyNewsDigest();
  printWinningLotteryNumbers();
  printWeatherForecast();
  printBaseballScore();
}

printWinningLotteryNumbers() {
  print('Winning lotto numbers: [23, 63, 87, 26, 2]');
}

printWeatherForecast() {
  print("Tomorrow's forecast: 70F, sunny.");
}

printBaseballScore() {
  print('Baseball score: Red Sox 10, Yankees 0');
}

const news = '<gathered news goes here>';
const oneSecond = Duration(seconds: 1);

// Imagine that this function is more complex and slow. :)
Future<String> gatherNewsReports() =>
    Future.delayed(oneSecond, () => news);
```

Answer (score 2):

`await` doesn't "remove" `then`, but it allows to write async code in a more convenient syntax as with `then` and kind of replaces `then`.
`await` is then rewritten back to `then` by the compiler.

`await` postpones the execution of the following code until the result of the awaited async operation is completed and returns the result value.
The result value is not a `Future` anymore and therefore `then()` is not available.

Comment: Thanks Günter - I am learning :-) I just found that when adding await it returns a string - defined in const news = '<gathered news goes here>'. So it kind of unwrap the Future<String>